# Remotely update database structure

Tags: javascript, mysql, ssh-tunnel

I am currently implementing an application on-premise using Docker containers. One of the docker containers is an actual MySQL database which gather local data of the client, coming from its private network.

I have also a RDS database that I am using as a blueprint for all the remote databases in the docker containers. I am currently facing some difficulties trying to update my remote databases.

The idea is that I want to be able to update the structure of all databases when important modifications are made on the cloud RDS database. My first intuition was to use bin logs on the RDS database but files are huge and event after treating the files to decrease the size, passing the actual commands take a very long time.

I must note that the remote databases are accessible through an SSH tunnel, which may be the reason why it’s so slow, but there is not much I can do about that.

Is this the right track to follow ? Is there another way to update databases  every month or so ?

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnzNw.jpg)